# Variable does not exist in the current context C# CodeBehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I recently upgraded my Visual Studio project from 2008 to 2012. After the upgrade I now get errors on all of the variables that previously worked in my C# file.

The name 'ddlVariable' does not exist in the current context...

A sample of my ASPX file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="mycode.aspx.cs" Inherits="myNameSpace.DoStuff" Title="Do Something" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
        <div style="clear: both; padding-top: 20px">
            <span style="float: left; width:125px">Some Words:</span>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlVariable" runat="server" Width="224px"/>
        </div>
    </asp:Content>
```

And my corresponding C# file:

```
namespace myNameSpace
{
    public partial class DoStuff : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsTrue)
            {
                // Populate Title drop down list
                ddlVariable.DataSource = Class.getInfo();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I have spent many hours trying to get my project working.

Thanks

Comment: Is your namespace really called `myNamespace` with a class called `DoStuff`?  I suspect that you've created this code as an example and hidden the real problem by doing it.

Comment: looks like the variable "ddlVariable" might be missing in the designer.cs page. could you please verify that

Comment: Try to clean the solution and build it again. Also check if the target framework has been modified by some reason.

Comment: @wizzards - I don't appear to have a designer.cs page. Guess that would be a pretty big problem.

Comment: @VinayKumar.o - yes, the framework version has been updated from 3.5 to 4.5

Comment: @Chimpy McGee - Change it back to 3.5 and re-build the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your aspx.designer.cs file may be corrupted.

Delete the corrupted aspx.designer.cs file form physical folder

Right click your Project file and select “Convert to Web Application“. I will generate new aspx.designer.cs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see a "Convert to Web Application" option on offer

Comment: Appreciate the help but it still does not appear in the drop down. I am using VS 2012

Comment: Please select your ASPX page and Right Click on it, you should get this menu

Comment: Do I need a NuGet package? I have none installed

Comment: Thanks for your help. I re-created my site and got it working.

Comment: Beware, Converting to a `Web Application` may cause other errors for your project. So, do it only if you know what you are doing.